Maximizing $\sum_x p(x) (f(x) - g(x) \log p(x))$ over discrete probability distribution $p(x)$
I want to solve this maximization problem over discrete probability distributions $p(x)$, where $f(x), g(x)$ are functions of $x$ and we have $g(x) > 0$.
$$
\sum_x p(x) (f(x) - g(x) \log p(x))
$$
I tried to solve this problem by taking the derivative with respect to $p(x)$ and setting it equal to zero:
$$f(x) - g(x)(\log p(x) +1) = 0$$
This gives a solution of $p(x) = \exp( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1)$. Because this may not sum to one, I normalize it: $p(x) = \frac{\exp( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1)}{\sum_x \exp( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 1)} = \frac{\exp( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)})}{\sum_x \exp( \frac{f(x)}{g(x)})}$. Is this approach correct? If not, what would be the correct derivation? Writing a Lagrangian introduces a variable and I'm not sure how to calculate it.

Your approach seems fine. It is not too hard to show that normalizing as you did will not change the stationary point. You do need to do some more work to determine whether this stationary point is a maximum.

Your approach is not correct. To deal with the constraint $\sum_xp(x)=1$, you should use a Lagrange multiplier, i.e., instead of maximizing
$$
F[p(x)]:=\sum_x p(x) (f(x) - g(x) \log p(x)), \tag{1}
$$
you should maximize
$$
G[p(x),\lambda]:=\sum_x p(x) (f(x) - g(x) \log p(x))+\lambda\left(\sum_x p(x)-1\right). \tag{2}
$$
To find the stationary points of $G$, one must solve
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial p(y)}=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{\partial G}{\partial\lambda}=0. \tag{3}
$$
The first equation yields
$$
f(y)-g(y)(\log p(y)+1)+\lambda=0 \implies p(y)=\exp\left(\frac{f(y)+\lambda}{g(y)}-1\right); \tag{4}
$$
the second,
$$
\sum_{x}p(x)=1. \tag{5}
$$
It follows from $(4)$ and $(5)$ that $\lambda$ is determined by the normalization condition
$$
\sum_x\exp\left(\frac{f(x)+\lambda}{g(x)}-1\right)=1. \tag{6}
$$
The solution to the problem is given by Eqs. $(4)$ and $(6)$.

+1 And in the end OP will need to check whether this $p$ maximizes or minimizes the functional.

… it seems plausible, at least to me, that, depending on the circumstances, $p(x_0) = 1$ for a specific $x_0$ could be a maximizer.

@Aruralreader To show that $p$ is a maximizer, is it sufficient to show that the second derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $p$ is negative?

@Aruralreader Or can we just say that if $g(x) > 0$, then this function is concave (because $-x \log x$ is concave) and thus the stationary point is maximizer?
